# .reset() function causing error instead of executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason I'm having trouble coding in to the reset button. I have this code:

```
 <form name="sub">
   ...
   <button type=submit>Submit</button>
   <button type=reset>Reset</button>
 </form>
```

When I click reset, it reset's the form, as usual.  However, when I try to bind a manual reset option on the button, like this code, it returns an error:

```
 var $f = $("form[name=sub]");

 $f.find("button[type=reset]").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $f.reset(); // <-- Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
   $(window).scrollTop(0);
 });
```

I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Tried using `document.form.sub.reset();` and tried `$f =` (global variable) instead of `var $f =` that doesn't work either. What's going on ?

Comment: You should be doing `$f[0].reset()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reset()` is a DOM method so use it on DOM object `$f[0]`

Answer (score 3):

Then you try `DOM 0` via `document.form.sub.reset();` you have misprint:

```
document.forms.sub.reset();
```

You can use it in jQuery, just get access to `node`:

```
 $("form[name=sub]").find("button[type=reset]").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $f.get(0).reset();//jQuery.fn.get return node, not jQuery object
   $(window).scrollTop(0);
 });
```